# ImportXML for Coinbase Prices

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to import the current value of the four cryptocurrencies that Coinbase offers into Google Sheets.

[image: Coinbase Charts with HTML]

Relevant HTML Line:

```
<div class="PriceChart__HeadingPrice-iOthZP gLGtWx Flex__Flex-fVJVYW iDqRrV">$14,188.72</div>
```

Formula:

```
=importxml("https://www.coinbase.com/charts",
           "//div[starts-with(@class,'PriceChart')]")
```

I expected to get the value of each `<div` with a `class` that starts with `PriceChart`.

Instead, I got the error: "Error: Imported content is empty"

What is wrong with my `xpath_query` parameter?

**EDIT:**

When the browser is too narrow, the currency values do not display in the `charts-header`.  They are also no longer in the HTML code.  I suspect Google Sheets gets different XML than my full-width browser.

If so, what is the workaround?

Comment: You can get required data by API request. Just use appropriate tool to send GET request to https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot and parse response as JSON...

Answer (score 0):

IMPORTXML is the wrong tool as it does not load content created by JavaScript.

I will have to import the cryptocurrency prices in a different way or from a different source.

> [Web Scraping Using ImportXML in Google Spreadsheets // Link To
>   Sheets](https://linktosheets.com/web-scraping-using-importxml-google-spreadsheets/)
>
> Unfortunately, ImportXML doesn’t load JavaScript, so you won’t be able
>   to use this function if the content of the document is generated by
>   JavaScript (jQuery, etc.)